# SQL error when running codeigniter project (mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given)

Tags: string, codeigniter, escaping

Ive just put my code igniter project only server, but when I go to login I get the error:

```
   **A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 316**
```

The login page itself if loading fine but the error appears.

This is my file:

```
 <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      EllisLab Dev Team
 * @copyright       Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @copyright       Copyright (c) 2014 - 2015, British Columbia Institute of Technology (http://bcit.ca/)
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * MySQLi Database Adapter Class - MySQLi only works with PHP 5
 *
 * Note: _DB is an extender class that the app controller
 * creates dynamically based on whether the active record
 * class is being used or not.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Drivers
 * @category    Database
 * @author      EllisLab Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/
 */
class CI_DB_mysqli_driver extends CI_DB {

    var $dbdriver = 'mysqli';

// The character used for escaping
var $_escape_char = '`';

// clause and character used for LIKE escape sequences - not used in MySQL
var $_like_escape_str = '';
var $_like_escape_chr = '';

/**
 * The syntax to count rows is slightly different across different
 * database engines, so this string appears in each driver and is
 * used for the count_all() and count_all_results() functions.
 */
var $_count_string = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS ";
var $_random_keyword = ' RAND()'; // database specific random keyword

/**
 * Whether to use the MySQL "delete hack" which allows the number
 * of affected rows to be shown. Uses a preg_replace when enabled,
 * adding a bit more processing to all queries.
 */
var $delete_hack = TRUE;

// whether SET NAMES must be used to set the character set
var $use_set_names;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Non-persistent database connection
 *
 * @access  private called by the base class
 * @return  resource
 */
function db_connect()
{
    if ($this->port != '')
    {
        return @mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $this->port);
    }
    else
    {
        return @mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    }

}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Persistent database connection
 *
 * @access  private called by the base class
 * @return  resource
 */
function db_pconnect()
{
    return $this->db_connect();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Reconnect
 *
 * Keep / reestablish the db connection if no queries have been
 * sent for a length of time exceeding the server's idle timeout
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  void
 */
function reconnect()
{
    if (mysqli_ping($this->conn_id) === FALSE)
    {
        $this->conn_id = FALSE;
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Select the database
 *
 * @access  private called by the base class
 * @return  resource
 */
function db_select()
{
    return @mysqli_select_db($this->conn_id, $this->database);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Set client character set
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @return  resource
 */
function _db_set_charset($charset, $collation)
{
    if ( ! isset($this->use_set_names))
    {
        // mysqli_set_charset() requires MySQL >= 5.0.7, use SET NAMES as fallback
        $this->use_set_names = (version_compare(mysqli_get_server_info($this->conn_id), '5.0.7', '>=')) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }

    if ($this->use_set_names === TRUE)
    {
        return @mysqli_query($this->conn_id, "SET NAMES '".$this->escape_str($charset)."' COLLATE '".$this->escape_str($collation)."'");
    }
    else
    {
        return @mysqli_set_charset($this->conn_id, $charset);
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Version number query string
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  string
 */
function _version()
{
    return "SELECT version() AS ver";
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Execute the query
 *
 * @access  private called by the base class
 * @param   string  an SQL query
 * @return  resource
 */
function _execute($sql)
{
    $sql = $this->_prep_query($sql);
    $result = @mysqli_query($this->conn_id, $sql);
    return $result;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Prep the query
 *
 * If needed, each database adapter can prep the query string
 *
 * @access  private called by execute()
 * @param   string  an SQL query
 * @return  string
 */
function _prep_query($sql)
{
    // "DELETE FROM TABLE" returns 0 affected rows This hack modifies
    // the query so that it returns the number of affected rows
    if ($this->delete_hack === TRUE)
    {
        if (preg_match('/^\s*DELETE\s+FROM\s+(\S+)\s*$/i', $sql))
        {
            $sql = preg_replace("/^\s*DELETE\s+FROM\s+(\S+)\s*$/", "DELETE FROM \\1 WHERE 1=1", $sql);
        }
    }

    return $sql;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Begin Transaction
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  bool
 */
function trans_begin($test_mode = FALSE)
{
    if ( ! $this->trans_enabled)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // When transactions are nested we only begin/commit/rollback the outermost ones
    if ($this->_trans_depth > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // Reset the transaction failure flag.
    // If the $test_mode flag is set to TRUE transactions will be rolled back
    // even if the queries produce a successful result.
    $this->_trans_failure = ($test_mode === TRUE) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    $this->simple_query('SET AUTOCOMMIT=0');
    $this->simple_query('START TRANSACTION'); // can also be BEGIN or BEGIN WORK
    return TRUE;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Commit Transaction
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  bool
 */
function trans_commit()
{
    if ( ! $this->trans_enabled)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // When transactions are nested we only begin/commit/rollback the outermost ones
    if ($this->_trans_depth > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    $this->simple_query('COMMIT');
    $this->simple_query('SET AUTOCOMMIT=1');
    return TRUE;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Rollback Transaction
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  bool
 */
function trans_rollback()
{
    if ( ! $this->trans_enabled)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // When transactions are nested we only begin/commit/rollback the outermost ones
    if ($this->_trans_depth > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    $this->simple_query('ROLLBACK');
    $this->simple_query('SET AUTOCOMMIT=1');
    return TRUE;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Escape String
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @param   bool    whether or not the string will be used in a LIKE condition
 * @return  string
 */
function escape_str($str, $like = FALSE)
{
    if (is_array($str))
    {
        foreach ($str as $key => $val)
        {
            $str[$key] = $this->escape_str($val, $like);
        }

        return $str;
    }


    $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn_id, $str);

    // escape LIKE condition wildcards
    if ($like === TRUE)
    {
        $str = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\\%', '\\_'), $str);
    }

    return $str;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Affected Rows
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  integer
 */
function affected_rows()
{
    return @mysqli_affected_rows($this->conn_id);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Insert ID
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  integer
 */
function insert_id()
{
    return @mysqli_insert_id($this->conn_id);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * "Count All" query
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific query string that counts all records in
 * the specified database
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function count_all($table = '')
{
    if ($table == '')
    {
        return 0;
    }

    $query = $this->query($this->_count_string . $this->_protect_identifiers('numrows') . " FROM " . $this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE));

    if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    $row = $query->row();
    $this->_reset_select();
    return (int) $row->numrows;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * List table query
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific query string so that the table names can be fetched
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   boolean
 * @return  string
 */
function _list_tables($prefix_limit = FALSE)
{
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$this->_escape_char.$this->database.$this->_escape_char;

    if ($prefix_limit !== FALSE AND $this->dbprefix != '')
    {
        $sql .= " LIKE '".$this->escape_like_str($this->dbprefix)."%'";
    }

    return $sql;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Show column query
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific query string so that the column names can be fetched
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @return  string
 */
function _list_columns($table = '')
{
    return "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Field data query
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific query so that the column data can be retrieved
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @return  object
 */
function _field_data($table)
{
    return "DESCRIBE ".$table;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * The error message string
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  string
 */
function _error_message()
{
    return mysqli_error($this->conn_id);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * The error message number
 *
 * @access  private
 * @return  integer
 */
function _error_number()
{
    return mysqli_errno($this->conn_id);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Escape the SQL Identifiers
 *
 * This function escapes column and table names
 *
 * @access  private
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
function _escape_identifiers($item)
{
    if ($this->_escape_char == '')
    {
        return $item;
    }

    foreach ($this->_reserved_identifiers as $id)
    {
        if (strpos($item, '.'.$id) !== FALSE)
        {
            $str = $this->_escape_char. str_replace('.', $this->_escape_char.'.', $item);

            // remove duplicates if the user already included the escape
            return preg_replace('/['.$this->_escape_char.']+/', $this->_escape_char, $str);
        }
    }

    if (strpos($item, '.') !== FALSE)
    {
        $str = $this->_escape_char.str_replace('.', $this->_escape_char.'.'.$this->_escape_char, $item).$this->_escape_char;
    }
    else
    {
        $str = $this->_escape_char.$item.$this->_escape_char;
    }

    // remove duplicates if the user already included the escape
    return preg_replace('/['.$this->_escape_char.']+/', $this->_escape_char, $str);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * From Tables
 *
 * This function implicitly groups FROM tables so there is no confusion
 * about operator precedence in harmony with SQL standards
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   type
 * @return  type
 */
function _from_tables($tables)
{
    if ( ! is_array($tables))
    {
        $tables = array($tables);
    }

    return '('.implode(', ', $tables).')';
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Insert statement
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific insert string from the supplied data
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @param   array   the insert keys
 * @param   array   the insert values
 * @return  string
 */
function _insert($table, $keys, $values)
{
    return "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".implode(', ', $keys).") VALUES (".implode(', ', $values).")";
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Insert_batch statement
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific insert string from the supplied data
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @param   array   the insert keys
 * @param   array   the insert values
 * @return  string
 */
function _insert_batch($table, $keys, $values)
{
    return "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".implode(', ', $keys).") VALUES ".implode(', ', $values);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------


/**
 * Replace statement
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific replace string from the supplied data
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @param   array   the insert keys
 * @param   array   the insert values
 * @return  string
 */
function _replace($table, $keys, $values)
{
    return "REPLACE INTO ".$table." (".implode(', ', $keys).") VALUES (".implode(', ', $values).")";
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Update statement
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific update string from the supplied data
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @param   array   the update data
 * @param   array   the where clause
 * @param   array   the orderby clause
 * @param   array   the limit clause
 * @return  string
 */
function _update($table, $values, $where, $orderby = array(), $limit = FALSE)
{
    foreach ($values as $key => $val)
    {
        $valstr[] = $key." = ".$val;
    }

    $limit = ( ! $limit) ? '' : ' LIMIT '.$limit;

    $orderby = (count($orderby) >= 1)?' ORDER BY '.implode(", ", $orderby):'';

    $sql = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ".implode(', ', $valstr);

    $sql .= ($where != '' AND count($where) >=1) ? " WHERE ".implode(" ", $where) : '';

    $sql .= $orderby.$limit;

    return $sql;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Update_Batch statement
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific batch update string from the supplied data
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @param   array   the update data
 * @param   array   the where clause
 * @return  string
 */
function _update_batch($table, $values, $index, $where = NULL)
{
    $ids = array();
    $where = ($where != '' AND count($where) >=1) ? implode(" ", $where).' AND ' : '';

    foreach ($values as $key => $val)
    {
        $ids[] = $val[$index];

        foreach (array_keys($val) as $field)
        {
            if ($field != $index)
            {
                $final[$field][] =  'WHEN '.$index.' = '.$val[$index].' THEN '.$val[$field];
            }
        }
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ";
    $cases = '';

    foreach ($final as $k => $v)
    {
        $cases .= $k.' = CASE '."\n";
        foreach ($v as $row)
        {
            $cases .= $row."\n";
        }

        $cases .= 'ELSE '.$k.' END, ';
    }

    $sql .= substr($cases, 0, -2);

    $sql .= ' WHERE '.$where.$index.' IN ('.implode(',', $ids).')';

    return $sql;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Truncate statement
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific truncate string from the supplied data
 * If the database does not support the truncate() command
 * This function maps to "DELETE FROM table"
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @return  string
 */
function _truncate($table)
{
    return "TRUNCATE ".$table;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Delete statement
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific delete string from the supplied data
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the table name
 * @param   array   the where clause
 * @param   string  the limit clause
 * @return  string
 */
function _delete($table, $where = array(), $like = array(), $limit = FALSE)
{
    $conditions = '';

    if (count($where) > 0 OR count($like) > 0)
    {
        $conditions = "\nWHERE ";
        $conditions .= implode("\n", $this->ar_where);

        if (count($where) > 0 && count($like) > 0)
        {
            $conditions .= " AND ";
        }
        $conditions .= implode("\n", $like);
    }

    $limit = ( ! $limit) ? '' : ' LIMIT '.$limit;

    return "DELETE FROM ".$table.$conditions.$limit;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Limit string
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific LIMIT clause
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the sql query string
 * @param   integer the number of rows to limit the query to
 * @param   integer the offset value
 * @return  string
 */
function _limit($sql, $limit, $offset)
{
    $sql .= "LIMIT ".$limit;

    if ($offset > 0)
    {
        $sql .= " OFFSET ".$offset;
    }

    return $sql;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Close DB Connection
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   resource
 * @return  void
 */
function _close($conn_id)
{
    @mysqli_close($conn_id);
}
```

}

/* End of file mysqli_driver.php */
/* Location: ./system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php */

All help is greatly appreciated!

My Model for the login:

```
  public function validate(){
    // grab user input
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password',($this->input->post('password')));


    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

My Controller:

```
 public function process()
{
    session_start();
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $query = $this->login_model->validate();


    if($query){
        // If there is a user, then create session data

        $data = array( // session variables
            'ID' => $this->user_model->getID($this->input->post('username')),
            'userID' =>$this->user_model->getUserID($this->input->post('username')),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'hospital' => $this->user_model->getHospital($this->input->post('username')),
            'class' => $this->user_model->getClass($this->input->post('username')),
            'is_logged_in' => true,

        );

      /*   if($this->user_model->getClass()){
               $this->session->set_flashdata('info', 'Admin Logged in');

           }
```

*/

```
       $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        //$this->load->view('admin_controller',$data);

      if($this->session->userdata('class') == 'Nurse') {
          redirect('files/nurse_dashboard');
      }
        else if($this->session->userdata('class') == 'Doctor') {

            redirect('files/docView');
        }

        else{

            redirect('login/admin');
        }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Login Successful');
        return true;




    }
   else {
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index($msg);
    }

}
```

Comment: The error occurs here mysqli/mysqli_driver.php. That is correct. But the Problem is in your Model / Controller. There you use the escape_str() function and $this->conn_id is false and not a mysqli object.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply! Ive updated the question to show my login model do you know what I'm doing wrong? @Webice